# How to stop sniffing upon user request

Tags: python, scapy

so I'm writing a code where I need to sniff until the user presses Ctrl C, imitating the sniff() function in scapy. I've tried many different ways but they won't work.
a part of the code here:

```
def stop_sniff_user(sig, frame):
    print("You pressed Ctrl + C")
    exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, stop_sniff_user)
packets = sniff()
while True:
    pass
```

and it gives this warning:

> WARNING: Socket <scapy.arch.pcapdnet.L2pcapListenSocket object at 0x0CBBC580> failed with '**call**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'. It was closed.

i've tried also using the KeyboardInterrupt exception, but Im pretty sure I don't know how to use it right also.

how do I do it right?

Answer (score 1):

Scapy sniff function is from AsyncSniffer class. You can create AsyncSniffer object and pass the parameters into it just like in the sniff function. Then call on that object start() and join() functions and when exception KeyboardInterrupt is catched just call stop() which will return the packets. Based on your code it would look like

```
try:
    sniffer = AsyncSniffer()
    sniffer.start()
    sniffer.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stop sniffing")
    packets = sniffer.stop()
```